# Jquery ajax posting wrong data

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, post

I have a a form:

```
<form id="deletesubmit" style="display:inline" >
    <input  style="width:50px" type="text" id="delcustomerid" name="delcustomerid" value="'.$row['customersid'].'">
    <button type="submit" class="table-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title="delete"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span></button>
</form>
```

The form gets the customers id and inserts it as value. It shows the correct customer is for that row everything is fine. Then when i post the form via ajax somehow it posts the id of a diffent row. This is the script:

```
$("form#deletesubmit").submit(function () {

    var delcustomerid = $('#delcustomerid').attr('value');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete/process.php",
        data: "delcustomerid=" + delcustomerid,
        success: refreshTable
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

And finally here is the php to post the form:

```
<?php include("../../config/config.php"); ?>
<?php          
    $deleteid  = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['delcustomerid']));
    mysql_send("DELETE FROM customers where id='$deleteid'");
?>
```

I have tested it without the ajax and it works fine. There must be something missing. It is not posting the correct value. Spent days trying to work it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `attr('value')` you are pulling the original value which may not what you want; use `.val()` instead. Also, you can setup your call a little easier:

```
$("form#deletesubmit").submit(function() {
  var delcustomerid  = $(this).find('#delcustomerid').val();
  $.post( "delete/process.php", { delcustomerid: delcustomerid }, refreshTable );
  return false;
});
```

Finally, make sure that your PHP is outputting the right `id` by viewing the source of the generated HTML.

**Also, in the PHP:** Don't use `htmlspecialchars` to escape mysql. Since this supposed to be an integer, you can just use `int`:

```
$deleteid  = (int) trim($_POST['delcustomerid']);
mysql_send("DELETE FROM customers where id='$deleteid'");
```

Keep in mind, that an array (if someone passed `deleteid[]=` to this page) would evaluate to `1`. So either build a test into it, or just make sure you don't have an `id` = 1 left in that table.

Comment: In addition, I do not believe that the way that "data" is formatted will function correctly.  The way that Doug has it formatted is the correct way. { delcustomerid: delcustomerid }

Comment: Thanks for the response. Added your code and the problem stills persists. Added alert(delcustomerid); prior to $.ajax as posted below and the wrong value is set before post.

Comment: Haha, I think I might know what's happening. Try my update (just the JS, I didn't change the PHP). Are you using multiple forms like this on single page?

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN!!!! YOU ARE THE MAN!!!!  YOU ARE THE MAN!!!! 

It works, It works, It works

Comment: Thankyou so much. I cannot tell you how long I have been looking at that page.

Comment: @user272899 Haha... glad it works! Since you used the same id twice on a page, it would always pull back the first one, not the one you wanted. You can avoid that in the future with using classes and that `find` trick I used. Good luck on the rest of your project!

Comment: I'm confused. If @Doug provided the correct answer, why wasn't his solution accepted?

Answer (score 2):

I was just going to suggest the .val() method. Also install firebug if you haven't already. It will allow you to see exactly what you are posting to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Put an alert into the code prior to the $.ajax({ like so:

```
alert(delcustomerid);
```

Is the value wrong right before the post?

Comment: added alert(delcustomerid); and yes the value is wrong before post. Does that mean it is a problem with the form??